# Angular 6 share data between components into template component via service

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have 2 different component, and 1 template component. I would like to pass the template component into the 2 other component ( I just put into the html the router outlet two time ). But.. 2 component has a uniq variable. like this: component_type="region", component_type="request". I try to share data between the service, and its works as well, but the shared data always the same. So I would like to bind the two components uniq property into the template component. The problem is on this picture.

[image]

So I want, that the first value is the first uniq id the second one is the second uniq id.

Thanks.
**My service.ts:**

```
@Injectable()

export class ObjectTemplateService {

  selectedRequest: string;

  private objectType$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('Default ntype');


  constructor(private http: Http,
              ) { }

  public setRequestTypeProperty(newrequestType: string): void {
    this.objectType$.next(newrequestType);
  }

  public getObjectType(): Observable<string> {
    return this.objectType$.asObservable();
  }

}
```

**My template component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-object-template',
  templateUrl: './object-template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./object-template.component.scss']
})
export class ObjectTemplateComponent implements OnInit {

  objectdata = REQUEST_DATA
  selectedRequest: string;
  selectedReq: RequestModel;

  public objectType: string;

  private getobjectTypeSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public objectTemplateService: ObjectTemplateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getobjectTypeSubscription = this.objectTemplateService.getObjectType()
      .subscribe((objectType: string) => {
        console.log('Object Template get these =>' + objectType)
        return this.objectType = objectType;

      });
  }

  onSelect(req: RequestModel): void {
    this.selectedReq = req;
  }

  getRequestType(request: RequestModel): void {
    this.objectTemplateService.getRequestType(request);
    this.selectedRequest = request.object_id
    this.objectTemplateService.changeMessage(request.object_id.toString())
    this.onSelect(request)
  }
}
```

**My template component.html**

```
Type: {{objectType}}
```

**First Component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-company',
  templateUrl: './company.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./company.component.css']
})
export class CompanyComponent implements OnInit {

  public object_type: string = 'company';

  constructor(public objectTemplateService: ObjectTemplateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.objectTemplateService.setRequestTypeProperty(this.object_type);
  }

}
```

**First Component.html**

```
<app-object-template></app-object-template>
```

**Second Component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-requests',
  templateUrl: './requests.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./requests.component.css']
})
export class RequestsComponent implements OnInit {

  public object_type: string = 'request';

  constructor( public objectTemplateService: ObjectTemplateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.objectTemplateService.setRequestTypeProperty(this.object_type);
  }
}
```

**Second Component.html**

```
<app-object-template></app-object-template>
```

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since services as shared across the entire app, modifying it from a component automatically modify it in another one. If you want to share a common template and code you can extend the base component:

**abstract-object-template.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-abstract-object-template',
  templateUrl: './abstract-object-template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./abstract-object-template.component.scss']
})
export class AbstractObjectTemplateComponent {

  objectdata = REQUEST_DATA
  selectedRequest: string;
  selectedReq: RequestModel;

  public objectType: string;

  constructor(objectType: string) {
    this.objectType = objectType;
  }

  onSelect(req: RequestModel): void {
    this.selectedReq = req;
  }

  getRequestType(request: RequestModel): void {
    this.objectTemplateService.getRequestType(request);
    this.selectedRequest = request.object_id
    this.objectTemplateService.changeMessage(request.object_id.toString())
    this.onSelect(request)
  }
}
```

**company.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-company',
  templateUrl: 'path/to/abstract-object-template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['path/to/abstract-object-template.component.scss']
})
export class CompanyComponent extends AbstractObjectTemplateComponent {

  constructor() {
    super('company');
  }

}
```

**requests.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-requests',
  templateUrl: 'path/to/abstract-object-template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['path/to/abstract-object-template.component.scss']
})
export class RequestsComponent extends AbstractObjectTemplateComponent {

  constructor() {
    super('request');
  }

}
```

Plus no additional *html* and *scss* files are required for "company" and "request" components.

Comment: Cool ! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like,  It reminds its previous value:

Implements OnDestroy method on your RequestsComponent and CompanyComponent
and add reset your service like this when destroying component:

```
          ngOnDestroy(): void {
            this.objectTemplateService.setRequestTypeProperty(null);
          }
```

Like this both:

```
            @Component({
              selector: 'app-requests',
              templateUrl: './requests.component.html',
              styleUrls: ['./requests.component.css']
            })
            export class RequestsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

              public object_type: string = 'request';

              constructor( public objectTemplateService: ObjectTemplateService) { }

              ngOnInit() {
                this.objectTemplateService.setRequestTypeProperty(this.object_type);
              }


                ngOnDestroy(): void {
                    this.objectTemplateService.setRequestTypeProperty(null);
                }


            }
```

Finally ObjectTemplateComponent unsubscribe service:

```
              ngOnDestroy(): void {
                this.subscription.unsubscribe();
              }
```